# Transaction in AutoMigration in .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm writing a simple application that uses Asp.NET 6 And This method update the database schema in run time but my problem is when migration throw an exception transaction.Rollback() not work
what should I do to solve this problem

this is my method

```
public async Task Initialize()
{
    using (var serviceScope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<PMOracleDbContext>())
        {
            using ( var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await dbContextTransaction.RollbackAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

and this my Program.cs

```
#region PmInitialDb

services.AddScoped<IPmDbInitializer, PmDbInitializerService>();
var dbInitializer = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IPmDbInitializer>();
dbInitializer.Initialize();
dbInitializer.SeedData();
    #endregion
```

and I use the OracelDb

Comment: As far as I know, by default Each ef core migration run in a transaction unless you pass suppressTransaction:true to the migrationBuilder. So you do not need wrapping the MigrateAsync() in another transaction. You can also rollback any migration one-by-one if you have configured all the Down methods properly. So I do not understand the need. Please elaborate.

Comment: you say "by default Each ef core migration run in a transaction" but why when auto migration throw Exceptions the database schema that updated not rollback like every transaction  @MDZand

Comment: Note that not ALL migrations are run in a transaction but each one in a separate one. So if one fails (it will rollback) the others may continue. If even one migration is not executed in a transaction it should be reported to be investigated further by ef team. Moreover this method of migration is not recommended for production environment. Take a look at this post:https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/handling-entity-framework-core-database-migrations-in-production-part-2/